# mediaplayer plug in error

Tags: html, firefox, plugins, google-chrome, media-player

I have created an html page with embedded audio in it, when I try to run it, Firefox and chrome do not display any media player on my HTML page. I recently downloaded a quicktime plugin but still Firefox does not identify it. May I know any supported media player plug-in for firefox and chrome?

here is the code:

```
<OBJECT id="Audio" 
        CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" 
        type="application/x-oleobject" 
        width="144" height="50">
   <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="music/Beethoven's Symphony No. 9 (Scherzo).wma">    
   <PARAM NAME="enabled" VALUE="True">    
   <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="False">    
   <PARAM name="PlayCount" value="3">    
   <PARAM name="Volume" value="50">    
   <PARAM NAME="balance" VALUE="0">    
   <PARAM NAME="Rate" VALUE="1.0">    
   <PARAM NAME="Mute" VALUE="False">    
   <PARAM NAME="fullScreen" VALUE="False">    
   <PARAM name="uiMode" value="full">    
</OBJECT>
```

Comment: i have deleted the "<" before the tag because it does not display when it is in html tag form so i deleted it but it actually has..

Answer (score 0):

WMA files aren't the most widely used/supported of files, so many of your end users would run into the same problems you're having.

A few options:

You might consider using a video service like youtube - upload it to youtube, and then cut and paste the "embed" code from them.

Even better, you could use a trial of an HTML5 video converting software, and code in an HTML5 solution.

Here is a link about inserting videos, with a section called "The Best HTML Solution" about half way down the page. 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Comment: A flash-based video player would be the easiest to install and have the most customers per time investment ratio.